# What do the Contour Levels Produced by Matlab Function Contourc Represent

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I have been trying to understand what the contour levels are.

As far as I understand a contour of the function Z(x,y) is a set of points in the (x,y) plane, such that Z(x,y) is fixed at some constant value, that constant value is the contour **level**. 
 
Matlab docs state that the contourc function takes an argument that determines the levels upon which the contours are computed. 
 
 
I wanted to try that out, so I constructed a picture with 10 rectangles, each of which has a distinct depth starting from 0.1 ending up at 1.0, and I ran the contour function to see the highlighted contours according to the specified levels in the input, but the results weren't expected.

For instance, I ran the code on 0.1 contour level and the contour function produces all the contours in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vra43.jpg), not only the ones with 0.1 level.

Here is the Matlab code used to construct the picture and find its contours:

```
pic = zeros(500, 500);
val = 0.1;
shift = 40;

for j = 1:10
  for i= 50:450
    pic(shift*j,i) = val;
  end
  for i= 50:450
    pic(shift*j+25,i) = val;
  end
  for i = shift*j: shift*j+25
    pic(i, 50) = val;
    pic(i,450) = val;
  end
  val = val + 0.1;

end

imshow(pic);
figure(2);
contour(pic, [0.1 0.1]);
```

I'd be so grateful if someone could clue me in.

Comment: Hi there! You may have noticed that SO is quite different from a forum. Here, you shouldn't add "[SOLVED]" to your posts once you got an adequate answer, because we understand that it's solved from the fact you have accepted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB contour plots represent data `Z` as a *continuous* function of `X` and `Y` by linearly interpolating between `Z` values supplied on a grid of `X` and `Y`.

The grid you've generated has value `0` throughout the background and values of `0.1` and higher in the various rectangular sections of the grid. Around *every* rectangular section, there is assumed linear gradient in value between the neighboring background grid values and the values you have assigned, and at some point that linear gradient *always* crosses `0.1` and a contour is drawn at that point.

We can see how this works more clearly by adding some more contour levels:

```
contour(pic, 0:0.02:0.1)
```

If we zoom in to the left hand edge of the bottom three boxes we get:

[image: Zoomed-in contours]

For all three boxes, `pic` is `0` at `X=49` and `X=51` along the side of the boxes. The bottom box has value `0.1` at `X=50` and so the `0.1`-contour is drawn exactly at that position.

The middle box reaches `0.2` at `X=50` and so the progression from `0` to `0.2` and back to `0` leads to `0.1`-contours occurring at `X=49.5` and again at `X=50.5`.

The top box reaches `0.3` at `X=50` and so the gradients are steeper and the `0.1`-contours are closer to the `0`-values at `X=49` and `X=51` compared to the middle box.

TL;DR: If your data has values that are either side of your contour level, the contour *always exists somewhere in between these values*.

Comment: Well explained, thank you.
Off-topic, since I understand what happens now, shall I close the question or mark it as solved? I don't have much experience in dealing with QA sites.

Comment: Solved is fine. It's probably not very likely, but if somebody wants to contribute their own answer which might answer the question better than mine, they should be free to do so. Questions stay up on the site not just for the original poster's benefit but for anyone else who might have the same question, so new answers always have the potential to be useful.